# MySQL Insert from 2 source tables to one destination table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys, left-join

I am having issues inserting Id fields from two tables into a single record in a third table.

```
mysql> describe ing_titles;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Title | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.22 sec)

mysql> describe ing_categories;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Category | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category    | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe ing_title_categories;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Title_Category | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ID_Title          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ID_Category       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Let's say the data from the tables is:

```
mysql> select * from ing_titles;
+----------+-------------------+
| ID_Title | title             |
+----------+-------------------+
|        3 | Chicken           |
|        2 | corn              |
|        1 | Fettucini Alfredo |
+----------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from ing_categories;
+-------------+----------+
| ID_Category | category |
+-------------+----------+
|           1 | Dinner   |
|           3 | Meat     |
|           2 | Veggie   |
+-------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to insert into `ing_title_categories` the record "corn, Veggie" or where ID_Title = 2 and ID_Category = 2.

Here's what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO ing_title_categories (ID_Title, ID_Category)
SELECT ing_titles.ID_Title, ing_categories.ID_Category
FROM ing_title_categories
    LEFT JOIN ing_titles ON ing_title_categories.ID_Title=ing_titles.ID_Title
    LEFT JOIN ing_categories ON ing_title_categories.ID_Category=ing_categories.ID_Category
WHERE (ing_titles.ID_Title=2) AND (ing_categories.ID_Category = 2);
```

There is no data inserted into the table `ing_title_categories`, and here is the reply from MySQL:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

What is the correct syntax for inserting the `ing_titles.ID_Title` and `ing_categories.ID_Category` into the table `ing_titles_categories`?

*Please, no PHP or Python examples.  Use SQL that I can copy and paste into the MySQL prompt.  I will be adding this to a C++ program, not PHP, JavaScript or Python.*

**Edit 1:** 
The `ing_title_categories.ID_Title` and `ing_title_categories.ID_Category` are foreign keys into the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking advice from @DrewPierce and @KaiserM11, here is the MySQL sequence:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ing_title_categories (ID_Title, ID_Category)
    -> SELECT
    ->     ing_titles.ID_Title,
    ->     ing_categories.ID_Category
    -> FROM ing_titles, ing_categories
    -> where (ing_titles.ID_Title = 2) AND (ing_categories.ID_Category = 2)
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from ing_title_categories;
+-------------------+----------+-------------+
| ID_Title_Category | ID_Title | ID_Category |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+
|                17 |        2 |           2 |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, only possible way I see is using a `UNION` query like

```
INSERT INTO ing_title_categories (ID_Title, ID_Category)

SELECT Title, NULL
FROM ing_title WHERE ID_Title = 2

UNION

SELECT NULL, category
FROM ing_categories
WHERE ID_Category = 2
```

(OR)

You can change your table design and use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to perform the same in one go.

**EDIT:**

If you can change your table design to something like below (No need of that extra chaining table)

```
ing_titles(ID_Title int not null auto_increment PK, title varchar(64) not null);

ing_categories( ID_Category int not null auto_increment PK,  
category varchar(64) not null, 
ing_titles_ID_Title int not null, 
FOREIGN KEY (ing_titles_ID_Title) 
        REFERENCES ing_titles(ID_Title));
```

Then you can use a `AFTER INSERT` trigger and do the insertion like

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ing_titles_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON ing_titles FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


   -- Insert record into ing_categories table
   INSERT INTO ing_categories
   ( category,
     ing_titles_ID_Title)
   VALUES
   ('Meat' NEW.ID_Title);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes, there is no relationship between `ing_titles` and `ing_categories`.  I am trying to get the `ing_titles.ID_Title` and `ing_categories.ID_Category` into a record in the `ing_title_categories` table.

Comment: Your table design is making it difficult to insert the data in chaining table. Else an trigger could be used to get this done.

Comment: What do you advise?  I'm working on using Normal forms.  I don't want to waste space with duplicating categories or titles.  A title is associated with a category.  A title-category pair represent the "title" of an ingredient.  Two ingredients with same title but different categories are considered as two separate ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO
    ing_title_categories (ID_Title, ID_Category)
SELECT
    ing_titles.ID_Title, ing_categories.ID_Category
FROM
    ing_titles, ing_categories
WHERE
    ing_titles.ID_Title = ing_categories.ID_Category AND
    ing_titles.ID_Title = 2 AND ing_categories.ID_Category = 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06470/1)

Comment: The destination table, `ing_title_categories`, has the fields:  `ID_Title_Category, ID_Title, ID_Category`.  There are no `Title` and `Category` fields in the table.  Here's the error from MySQL:  `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Title' in 'field list'`